# One last step! (python tuning)

Tags: python, join, functional-programming

I have this code:

```
        emailRows = []
        for rowTuple in listOfRows: #row loop
            emailLine = []
            for tup in rowTuple: #field loop
                emailLine.append(str(tup).center(20))                
            emailRows.append('\t'.join([field.strip().center(20) for field in emailLine]))
        rows = '\n'.join(emailRows)
        emailBody = emailBody + rows
```

which i've so far changed to this code:

```
        emailRows = []
        for rowTuple in listOfRows: #row loop
            emailRows.append('\t'.join([field.strip().center(20) for field in [str(tup).center(20) for tup in rowTuple]]))
        rows = '\n'.join(emailRows)
        emailBody = emailBody + rows
```

I'm not sure but it seems like I can get rid of the last for loop somehow. I need some help doing this, though.

Comment: Is the difference in speed really that dramatic? Your second block of code is much harder to read.

Comment: Profile it, that's the only way you'll know if making it into comprehensions/using map was worthwhile.

Comment: I guess this is really just more of an intellectual exercise for my own edification.

Comment: @Ramy: Profiling is the important intellectual exercise.  Hypothetical "which is faster?" questions aren't important.  The only way to answer the hypothetical is to actually run experiments using the profiler.

Comment: You didn't even seem to ask a question.  Doing what?  Why do you want to get rid of the loop?  "One last step" is not a meaningful question title.

Comment: so, how do I profile a python script? Maybe that's the better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'\n'.join(('\t'.join([field.strip().center(20) for
    field in [str(tup).center(20) for
        tup in rowTuple]])) for rowTuple in listOfRows)
```

Wow, that's obfuscated. I hope cProfile says this guy is a heavy hitter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced the result is worth the effort, but if you're going to go down the route of eliminating all your `for` loops in favour of comprehensions, you should note that you can use [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) instead of list comprehensions to avoid creating (and then throwing away) intermediate lists.

Comment: this is exactly why i posted this. To learn something new. Thanks, Gareth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` instead `for x in seq`:

```
rows='\n'.join(map(lambda row: '\t'.join(map(lambda cell: str(cell).center(20), row)), listOfRows))
```

Also you can try `reduce()` instead `join()`:

```
def cell_format(cell):
    return str(cell).center(20)

def row_format(res, cell):
    return res+'\t'+cell

def rows_format(res, row):
    return res+'\n'+row

rows=reduce(rows_format,
            map(lambda row: reduce(row_format, map(cell_format, row)),
                listOfRows))
```

But you first example looks much more pretty))